# One ng-options is dependent on what is selected in another - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a form in AngularJS where the options for one of the dropdowns depends on what is selected in the first.

```
<select ng-options="obj.name for obj in institutions track by obj.id" ng-model="newUser.institution">
</select>

<input type="text" name="email" ng-model="newUser.email">

<!-- DEPENDENT on what is selected in the previous dropdown -->
<select ng-options="obj.name for obj in organizations track by obj.id" ng-model="newUser.associatedOrg">
</select>
```

Institutions are all loaded right off the bat from available institutions in the database. That is done in the controller like this:

```
function populate() {
    return Institutions.all().then(function (institutions) {
        $scope.institutions = institutions;
        return institutions;
    });
}

// at the end of the controller
populate();
```

However, those "organizations" in the second dropdown are based on their parent table institution, so I need to do something like `$scope.organizations = institution.memberOrganizations;` in the controller **after** an option from the first dropdown is selected.

For now, just to make sure things work, I have made a button called "Load Organizations" with an `ng-click` for this function:

```
$scope.getOrganizationsOnCampus = function(institution) {
    $scope.organizations = institution.memberOrganizations;
};
```

That works, however that is a really bad user experience.

**So my question is: How do I update `$scope.organizations` every time a new institution is selected?**

I want to do this without listening to the DOM - like you would in jQuery, because I know that is **way** against the AngularJS best practices.

P.S. For further clarity, here is a screenshot of before, and after that "Load Organizations" button is clicked, to load the child organizations of the selected institution. This is what I want to automatically do every time a different institution is selected in the previous option.

**BEFORE**

[image: before you update child organizations]

**AFTER**

[image: after you update child organizations - right now with a ghetto button click!]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would you use `ng-change` like this:

```
<select ng-options="obj.name for obj in institutions track by obj.id" ng-model="newUser.institution" ng-change"updateOrg(newUser.institution)">
</select>
```

and then in your controller, you have a function like this:

```
$scope.updateOrg = function(institution) {
    $scope.organizations = institution.memberOrganizations;
};
```